# Determine whether $(\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(y^2-x^2-x^3))_{(x,y)}$ is a discrete valuation ring.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Geometrically, the curve $y^2-x^2-x^3=0$ is singular at the origin in the real plane. Thus the ring should not be a dvr.

I am thinking to show that it is not a dvr, it is equivalent to show that it is not integrally closed in its fraction field $K=Quot((\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(y^2-x^2-x^3))_{(x,y)})$. I cannot determine what $K$ is. Also, I am suspecting that one of $x/y$ and $y/x$ is an element of $K$ integral over the ring but not contained in it. Is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not really need to know the quotient field. You know that $t=\frac{y}{x} \in K$ and $t^2=\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2 = 1+x$, hence $t$ is integral over the ring, but not contained in the ring. This shows what you want.

By the way: For a one-dimensional noetherian local integral domain, the following four properties are equivalent: DVR, the maximal ideal is principal, regular, normal.

Thus it would also suffice to show that you ring is not regular and for that, we have another general lemma:

If $R$ is a regular local ring and $I \neq 0$ an ideal with $I \subset \mathfrak m^2$, then $R/I$ is not regular. This follows from $$(\mathfrak m/I)/(\mathfrak m/I)^2 = (\mathfrak m/I)/(\mathfrak m^2+I/I) = (\mathfrak m/I)/(\mathfrak m^2/I) = \mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$$
This shows that the dimension of cotangent space is invariant but the dimension of the ring decreases, hence the regularity is gone.

Comment: For the sake of completion: The quotient field is $$\mathbb R(x)[y]/(y^2-x^2-x^3) \cong \mathbb R(x,\sqrt{x^2+x^3})$$

Comment: I see. I do recall we learned that the if the given ring is regular, then the dimension of the tangent space at the origin should be equal to the dimension of the variety. But in this case, the dimension of the variety is 1 where the dimension of the tangent space is 2.